# Is it possible to find SharePoint SKU using JSOM/CSOM/REST api

Tags: 2013, csom, jsom

Is there a way to find the locally installed SKU of SharePoint using any client side scripting?

I am only able to find [server side code](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/how-to-detect-the-installed-sku-of-sharepoint)  for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get the SKU via client side, as this information stored inside the registry key. But from client side you can get the server version.

```
string url = @"http://yourweburl";
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url);
context.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine(context.ServerVersion.Major.ToString());
```

[How to find SharePoint Version](http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/different-ways-to-get-sharepoint-versions/)